# How to run user defined pod correctly in Kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, local, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes. I installed it on my local Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I want to run nginx server and I want see it in my browser.  I'm following this [section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/locally.md#running-a-user-defined-pod).

It's saying

> However you cannot view the nginx start page on localhost. To verify that nginx is running you need to run curl within the docker container (try docker exec).

I tried below instruction to check server is running.

```
# docker exec -it d0ef46bcdb8b bash
root@nginx:/# service ngix status
nginx is running.
```

Now I want to see it in webpage.

> You can control the specifications of a pod via a user defined manifest, and reach nginx through your browser on the port specified therein:
>
> cluster/kubectl.sh create -f examples/pod.yaml

But I don't how to edit the manifest. How I get nginx through browser?

Answer (score 1):

The manifest that the documentation is referring to is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/pod.yaml). Copy this file onto your local machine (or find it on your system if you've already downloaded a copy of the git repository). You can edit the file using your favorite web browser and then run `kubectl create -f pod.yaml` to tell the system to create the pod.